# Github atom editor shows line deleted and added back

Tags: atom-editor

I am using Github's atom text editor.
Most of the times, when I modify a single line in a file, `git diff` shows a lot of lines as deleted and added back in this way

```
 -      @op_contact = "Not Available" 
 +      @op_contact = "Not Available"
```

This causes inconvenience in code-reviews and hence I am forced to use other editors like SublimeText.

It looks like some simple setting should fix this, but I am not sure how to do it and I don't know what to search for. There are some related questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452675/git-diff-shows-the-same-line-as-both-deleted-and-added) but I want to fix it from Atom editor, as this problem is not present in SublimeText.

Atom version: 1.3.1

Comment: Usually that's a whitespace difference (tab vs space, trailing spaces, etc). Diff viewers can be set up to ignore those.

Comment: Seems your project needs a coding style guide if files just have tabs, spaces, trailing spaces etc.

Comment: @MartinBean Yes... We are working on ruby on rails and currently not using any style guides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably searching for the Whitespace package which ships with Atom by default.

It removes unnecessary whitespace at the end of each line. Disable it and your suspicious line changes should be gone.

[image: Atom Whitespace package]

Comment: Disabling this removed my problem. Accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks!! Spent about 30 mins trying to figure out what setting was doing that...