# Git automatically remove trailing-space

Tags: git, atom-editor

When I pull from remote branch, Git automatically removes all the trailing-space and it masses up my git diff (showing line deleting and adding). Also I'm using Atom editor so I'm not too sure where the problem came from.

How can I disable trimming the trailing-space? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `git diff -w`.

Comment: It looks like this has turned out to be a duplicate of [Github atom editor shows line deleted and added back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896982/github-atom-editor-shows-line-deleted-and-added-back/34897198)

Comment: Yeah. I found my answer in one of the atom discussions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the problem with git is that it doesn't automatically remove trailing whitespace leading to excessive conflicts when the diffs only have whitespace differences.  See this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing) (among many).

However, I did find some discussion GitHub about Atom settings with respect to leaving trailing whitespace (or not).  So I would look to the Atom setting first for your solution (e.g., [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib3dfv09fMAhXBdj4KHf2WAsMQFghGMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fatom%2Fwhitespace%2Fissues%2F10&usg=AFQjCNHgNbtT3HJRaVR6eWq_rVx1DVu63g&sig2=Pb2xAJNIGWduxnYbfczHTQ)).

Comment: The whitespace package can be annoying sometimes so I just disabled it.. Thank you very much!